# Search refiner filters displayed in a popup window

Tags: search, popup, refiner

We have too many filter values in the Search refiner, and the requirement is that instead of the user scrolling down so many refiners, they should be able to see them in a pop up window when they click on **"Show More"**, with `checkboxes` beside each refiner value for the user to select.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

On the click of `Show More` do something like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openBasicDialog(Url, Title) {        
    var options = { url: Url, title: Title};  
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);      
}       
</script> 

<a href="#" onclick="openBasicDialog('qweryt.aspx','PopUp');">Show More</a>
```